# Why Unhandled exception tricks not working in all cases

Tags: c#, exception

I ve got an application that runs on many computers (Win 7/10/Server 2012/2016)
Sometime I've got this issue.

```
Faulting application name: app_manager.exe, version: 4.12.16.0, time stamp: 0x5efca010
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.18362.815, time stamp: 0xb89efff3
...

Exception Info: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginReceive(Byte[], Int32, Int32, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
   at app_manager.FormSystray.AcceptCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(System.Object, IntPtr)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AcceptCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.RegisteredWaitCallback(System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.PerformWaitOrTimerCallback(System.Object, Boolean)
```

It's seems this code bellow not work in every case.

```
    [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
    [SecurityCritical]
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(String[] aCmdLine)
    {
        ...

        // Set the unhandled exception mode to force all Windows Forms errors to go through our handler.
        // Add the event handler for handling non-UI thread exceptions to the event. 
        Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
        Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
```

My only function that use AcceptCallback was place in a try catch !

```
oListener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), oListener);
```

Did someone have any idea to handle all exception.

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: `My only function that use AcceptCallback was place in a try catch !` Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Are you using the Windows Socket or the c# socket?  The two are not the same and do not work together.  When Microsoft created the Net Library they decided that were too many issues with the standard windows socket class and rewrote the socket class in Net.  the exception indicates your are using the Windows socket : KERNELBASE.dll.  The oListener.BeginAccept indicates you are also using the c# socket : oListener.BeginAccept

Comment: I use this 
```
public static void StartListening()
{
 Socket oListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
 try
 {
  oListener.Bind(oLocalEndPoint);
  oListener.Listen(100);
  while (!_bClose)
  {
   oAllEvent.Reset();
   oListener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), oListener);
   oAllEvent.WaitOne();
  }
 }
 catch (Exception oEx) { _bClose = true; }
}
```
But my post question is why UnhandledException  dose not work.
Maybe they are some exception that we cannot catch ?